# Compare the value with the next 5 rows value if there is a 10% increase

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

EXCEL how to compare the value and next 5 rows value if there is a 10% increase. something like that if (A1 > A2*1.1 or A1 > A3*1.1...or A1 > A5*1.1) then return true;

```
  A B C D E
1 1
2 1.1
3 0.9
4 0.9
5 0.9
6 0.9
7 0.9
H 0.9
```

Comment: Do you want to compare each value with its next 5 values? Please share sample table of expected output.

Comment: yes, for example row A, it return true because B > A and B >= A * 10%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula for this.

Example:

[image]

Note you need to enter the formula using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you drag it down (it checks for empty cells aswell)

```
=ISNUMBER(OFFSET(A1,MATCH(TRUE,A1>=(A2:A6*1.1),0),0))
```

Enter with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility using a non-array, non-volatile standard formula.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(MAX(A1*1.1, A2:A6), A2:A6, 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: max_next_5]